# What is resource in magento

Tags: php, magento

I started learning Magento.I created custom module.I have controller in that action i getting the array of data. But when i tried to get same collecion in Block file. I didn't got the collection. 
Should i need to create resource folder to get data in Block ? I already created Mysql4 folder in Model. What is the real use of resource ?  How to create resource ?
My Namespace is Company and my Module name is web 
Here is my Block file name - Web.php

```
<?php
class Company_Web_Block_Webdata extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
     public function getCategoryData()
     {
         return Mage::getModel('web/web')->getCollection()->getData();
     }
}


?>
```

My config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Web>
            <version>1.6.0.0.2</version>
        </Company_Web>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <web>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Web</module>
                    <frontName>web</frontName>
                </args>
            </web>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <web>
                    <file>web.xml</file>
                </web>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

    <global>
         <models> 
                <!--<web>
                       <class>Company_Web_Model</class>
                       <resourceModel>web_mysql4</resourceModel>        
               </web>
               <web_mysql4>
                   <class>Company_Web_Model_Mysql4</class>
                   <entities>
                       <web>
                           <table>category</table>
                       </web>
                   </entities>                
               </web_mysql4>-->
                <web>
                   <class>Company_Web_Model</class>
                   <resourceModel>web_resource</resourceModel>        
                </web>
                <web_resource>
                    <class>Company_Web_Model_Resource</class>
                    <entities>
                        <web>
                            <table>category</table>
                        </web>
                    </entities>                
                </web_resource>
         </models>
         <resources> 
             <web_setup>
                 <setup>
                     <module>Company_Web</module>  
                 </setup>
                 <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
             </web_setup>
             <web_setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </web_setup>
            <web_setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </web_setup>
         </resources>
         <blocks> 
             <company_web>
                 <class>Company_Web_Block</class>
             </company_web>
         </blocks>
         <!--
         <helpers> 
             <company_web>
                 <class>Company_Web_Helper</class>
             </company_web>
         </helpers>-->
    </global>
</config>
```

Web.php file In Resource folder.

```
 <?php
class Company_Web_Model_Resource_Web extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
        protected function _construct()
        {
                $this->_init('web/web', 'id');
        }
} 


?>
```

Collection.php file Resource/Web/collection.php

```
<?php
class Company_Web_Model_Resource_Web_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
        protected function _construct()
        {
                $this->_init('web/web');
        } 
}

?>
```

IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Company_Web_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {    
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function addcategoryAction()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) 
        {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $catName = $data['catName'];
            $status = $data['status'];
            $data = array('name'=>$catName,'status'=>$status);
            $model = Mage::getModel('web/web')->setData($data);
            try {
                $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
                $this->_redirect('web/index/category');
            } catch (Exception $e){
             echo $e->getMessage();   
            }

        }
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function categoryAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}

?>
```

layout/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <web_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="web" template="web/web.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </web_index_index>

    <web_index_addcategory>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="web" template="web/addcategory.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </web_index_addcategory>

    <web_index_category>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="category" template="web/category.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </web_index_category>
</layout>
```

Comment: The block file shouldn't be Web.php but Webdata.php, Web.php should be your model file.

Comment: Thanks.I change the name as per your comments.

Comment: Not yet.Can you please tell me what is real use of resource ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to interact with database you have to use the Resource Model, you can use some generic functions like `load`,`_beforeload`, `_afterLoad`, `_afterSave` etc in it. Even your custom queries can go here. But to use resource model, there should be a `Model` and `Collection` class also declared. In your case there should be three files as following:

- **Model File:** `Model/Web.php`
- **Resource File:** `Model/Resource/Web.php`
- **Collection file:** `Model/Resource/Web/Collection.php`

Please update your `config.xml` for the `models` tag as following:

```
<models> 
    <web>
        <class>Company_Web_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>web_resource</resourceModel>        
    </web>
    <web_resource>
        <class>Company_Web_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <web>
                <table>category</table>
            </web>
        </entities>                
    </web_resource>
</models>
```

Please update your layout file as:

```
<web_index_category>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="web/webdata" name="category" template="web/category.phtml" />
    </reference>
</web_index_category>
```

Comment: I already created that file. Please check my update. I did that as per your comments. Still didn't got any data.

Comment: When i added category it works with this resource.But i didn't get that list of category in block

Comment: can you post the category table's fields? or the setup file

Comment: I also added my controller and layout xml file

Comment: Please check my layout file. Does it fine ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56873/discussion-between-mtm-and-nikul).